# Insert comma after numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

In this code I'm trying to read multiple files in a folder, and insert a comma after each number.
In the first file it works well, but in the second file there are two commas inserted after each number, something like this:

> ```
> 56,, 
> 74,,
> 2,,
> ```

How can I insert just one comma?

```
input_path = Path(Path.home(), "Desktop", "m")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = Path(root, file)
        
        with open(file_path) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
        with open('C:/--/{}.txt'.format(file), "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line + ",\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're not inserting a comma after the number, you're inserting a comma after every line. You'll want to check if there's a comma at the end of the line is a comma doing something like this

```py
def endsInComma(line):
    return line.endswith(',')
```

If the function returns true, don't append a comma, if it returns false, then append a comma at the end of the line

Comment: @buran just edited the str, I'm not used to python as I primarily do C# and forgot it was a reserved keyword. Does `.endswith()` provide a performance advantage?

Comment: It's [pep8 recommended way](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id47) to check for sufix.

Comment: This does not solve the problem!

Comment: @oleva update your post explaining what's happening now and what the code looks like now

Comment: my calling was wrong :) , now good :)